# join on multiple columns

Tags: sql, t-sql

I have two tables (Table A and Table B) which I want to join on multiple columns in both tables.

```
Table A                         
Col1     Col2                
================            
A11      A21                 
A22      A22              
A33      A23                 

Table B 
Col1     Col2   Val 
=================  
B11     B21     1  
B12     B22     2  
B13     B23     3
```

I want both Columns in Table A to join on either of Col1 and Col2 in Table B to get Val.

Comment: The example data you have posted would return no results. Are the `A` values actually prefixed `A` and the `B` ones `B`? Also this is a very smelly requirement if the columns are interchangeable in this manner it indicates the design is not normalised.

Comment: The way I put my data may seems there's no result. Please ignore how the data are constructed in table.

Answer (score 65, accepted):

Agree no matches in your example.
If you mean both columns on either then need a query like this or need to re-examine the data design.

```
    Select TableA.Col1, TableA.Col2, TableB.Val
    FROM TableA
    INNER JOIN TableB
          ON TableA.Col1 = TableB.Col1 OR TableA.Col2 = TableB.Col2 
          OR TableA.Col2 = TableB.Col1 OR TableA.Col1 = TableB.Col2
```

Comment: I agree that there won't be match with how my data is constructed. I made up the data on the fly for an illustration. Please ignore the data.      <br> Basically, I'm trying to achieve many to many relationship without a mapping table.

Answer (score 28):

The other queries are all going base on any ONE of the conditions qualifying and it will return a record... if you want to make sure the BOTH columns of table A are matched, you'll have to do something like...

```
select 
      tA.Col1,
      tA.Col2,
      tB.Val
   from
      TableA tA
         join TableB tB
            on  ( tA.Col1 = tB.Col1 OR tA.Col1 = tB.Col2 )
            AND ( tA.Col2 = tB.Col1 OR tA.Col2 = tB.Col2 )
```

Answer (score 3):

Below is the structure of SQL that you may write. You can do multiple joins by using "AND" or "OR".

```
Select TableA.Col1, TableA.Col2, TableB.Val
FROM TableA, 
INNER JOIN TableB
 ON TableA.Col1 = TableB.Col1 OR TableA.Col2 = TableB.Col2
```

Answer (score 0):

```
tableB.col1 = tableA.col1 
OR tableB.col2 = tableA.col1  
OR tableB.col1 = tableA.col2  
OR tableB.col1 = tableA.col2
```