# Wrong data results on multiple joins (mysql query)

Tags: mysql, join

I am trying to join multiple tables with their foreign keys to be able to access the other colums. I have the query below, and this result shows a table with duplicate data

current results

```
+-----------+-----------+----------+----------+-------------+-------------+-----+
| ponumber  | drNumber  | itemCode | itemName | receivedQty | rejectedQty | ... |
+-----------+-----------+----------+----------+-------------+-------------+-----+
|  00000001 | 000000002 | 13333333 | button   |           1 |           0 |     |
|  00000001 | 000000002 | 13333333 | button   |          20 |           0 |     |
+-----------+-----------+----------+----------+-------------+-------------+-----+
```

Expected Result

```
+-----------+-----------+----------+----------+-------------+-------------+-----+
| ponumber  | drNumber  | itemCode | itemName | receivedQty | rejectedQty | ... |
+-----------+-----------+----------+----------+-------------+-------------+-----+
|  00000001 | 000000002 | 13333333 | button   |           1 |           0 |     |
|  00000001 | 000000002 | 13333331 | pajama   |          20 |           0 |     |
+-----------+-----------+----------+----------+-------------+-------------+-----+
```

it looks like the query is getting the information needed which is 2 rows, but the results are not correct.

```
 SELECT SPO.poNumber
    ,SDR.drNumber
    ,I.itemCode
    ,I.itemName
    ,SDR.receivedQty
    ,SDR.rejectedQty
    ,SPO.volumeQty
    ,SPO.dateMade
    ,SPO.deliveryDate
    ,U.lastName AS preparedbyLastName
    ,U.firstName AS preparedbyFirstName
    ,S.unitPrice
    ,I.unitMeasurement
    ,I.inventoryType
    ,SPO.receivingStatus
    ,SPO.notes
FROM ref_item I
JOIN ref_supplier S ON S.itemCode = I.itemCode
JOIN supplier_purchase_order SPO ON SPO.supplier = S.supplierID
JOIN supplier_delivery_receipt SDR ON SDR.poNumber = SPO.poNumber
JOIN user U ON SPO.preparedBy = U.employeeID
WHERE SPO.poNumber = 70000006
    AND SPO.receivingStatus != "complete"
ORDER BY itemName;
```

the tables that are affected are ref_item, ref_supplier, supplier_purchase_order and supplier_delivery_receipt

[image]

Comment: What problem are you solving? What are your test data?

Comment: I am trying to join multiple tables with their foreign keys to be able to access the other colums

Comment: You have to show us structure of both tables and desired output. Then we can see problem with your query.

Comment: Can you please add sample data for all the table.

Comment: I added the table design... @KuKeC

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you will need to include all the primary keys in joining by using `ON` and `AND`.

```
  "SELECT   SPO.poNumber, SPO.itemCode, S.companyName, SPO.volumeQty, S.companyName, SPO.dateMade, \n"
                            + "SPO.deliveryDate, U.lastName as preparedbyLastName , U.firstName as preparedbyFirstName, \n"
                            + "S.unitPrice,I.itemName, I.unitMeasurement, I.inventoryType, SPO.notes, SPO.receivingStatus\n"
                            + "           FROM supplier_purchase_order SPO\n"
                            + "           JOIN ref_supplier S\n"
                            + "       ON SPO.itemCode = S.itemCode\n"
                            + "AND SPO.supplier = S.supplierID\n"
                            + "JOIN ref_item I\n"
                            + "ON S.itemCode = I.itemCode\n"
                            + "JOIN user U\n"
                            + "ON SPO.preparedBy = U.employeeID\n"
                            + "WHERE  SPO.poNumber = ? AND SPO.receivingStatus != 'complete';"
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to link your tables by all columns which are represented as primary key and linked to other table as foreign key.

For example your table `supplier_purchase_order` and table `supplier_delivery_receipt` are linked with columns `poNumber` and `itemCode` but in your query you only have 1 column

```
JOIN supplier_delivery_receipt SDR ON SDR.poNumber = SPO.poNumber
```

You need to put both columns in each join. To get more informations about how to solve this check [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7183364/join-on-multiple-columns).

Hope it helps you