# Database foreign key in either one or another column

Tags: database, join, database-design

Is it possible to link one table to another table even if its not clear in which column the foreign key appear?

Example:

Table 'server' has (among others) two fields -> 'internal ip' and 'external ip'

Another table 'server_details' has only a field 'ip'.

'server_details' and 'server' should be joined at the ip.

The problem is, we don't know if the ip  in the server_details  is the external or internal ip, so it could appear in the one or in the other column, but every ip (should be) unique for the whole database and will match definitely one dataset in one of two possible fields.

Can somebody tell me how to realise this? Or isn't it possible at all?

I have to map this behaviour to doctrine entitys at last ...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [join on multiple columns](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7183364/1072229)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [join on multiple columns](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7183364/join-on-multiple-columns)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was gone because at least we redefined our datamodel anyway. Thanks for your help anyway!

Answer (score 0):

I think you are going at it the opposite way.

`server.internal_ip` and `server.external_ip` can have a foreign key relationship to `server_details.ip`

Comment: Thats a good suggestion ... ill give a try to give both the foreign key and set server_details.ip constraint to "not null". Maybe that will work.

Comment: Okay, i found out, that probably will not work for my situation ... i cant add a foreign key to the server_details.ip without making the target field (server.internal_ip/server.external_ip) unique, because the internal ip could appear more than one time. The rule is the following: If an external ip exist, take this as foreign key. if not, take the internal ip ... this key has to be unique for all entrys with just an internal ip ... complicated :/

Comment: Is server_details.ip unique?  If so, server.internal_ip/server.external_ip wouldn't have to be unique.  Basically server_details.ip could be the primary key for that table?

Comment: the server_details.ip isn't unique, because one server could have one or more server details

Comment: Maybe i should use 2 Tables for internal / external machines/ips

Answer (score 0):

The idea of linking tables is a relic of the network data model. In relational databases, we can define foreign key constraints (integrity constraints which ensure one column's values exist in another, but which doesn't create or limit access paths) and join tables (on any condition, regardless of FK constraints). However, your use of Doctrine may limit you in this regard since object-relational mappers try to reinvent network model databases.

You can easily join `server` to `server_details`:

```
SELECT *
FROM server_details sd
INNER JOIN server s ON sd.ip = s.internal_ip OR sd.ip = s.external_ip
```

or possibly

```
INNER JOIN server s ON sd.ip = COALESCE(s.external_ip, s.internal_ip)
```

An FK constraint is a separate matter. If none of your columns uniquely represent the domain of IPs, an FK constraint may not be appropriate. It may be possible to refactor your design to make it more amenable to integrity constraints. If you post your schema or list functional dependencies, I could amend my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You should consider adding an id field to server that can be declared as a PK, unless server already has a PK.  Then, put a field called server_id in server_details and declare that as a FK that references server.id.  Now, the join is easy:

```
SELECT *
FROM server_details sd
INNER JOIN server s ON sd.server_id = s.id
```

The id field serves no other purpose than to uniquely identify a server.  You can use the autonumber feature of your DBMS to assign new values.

I'm not sure how this is affected by Doctrine.